# Theory about development real-time chat application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

I have theoretical question about real-time application, something like messenger app. We develop our own application for intern purposes. We also need append coming messages in real-time and also implement paging for loading previous messages and pagination.

Here is my vision how to do that but I don't know if it's correct.

We implement 2 types of controllers, for REST and Websockets. So in practice it should looks something like that:

1. User is connected into application which cause creation of channel for websocket.
2. Next will be loaded previous 0..X messages from REST api.
3. When user scrolls up it will be loaded next X..Y messages.
4. When user sends message it will be send over websockets and in websocket controller will call service for storing message in DB, and next send to other recipients.

Is that vision OK? It's ok to use websockets and REST in same project? Any next advice?

Our supposed tech stack:

- Spring Boot
- Spring Websocket
- Spring MVC
- PostgreSQL

Comment: Could this be part of a better vision ? https://www.codeproject.com/articles/524066/signalr-simple-chat-application-in-csharp

Comment: @MarcRoussel yes it's similar to mine, but I also need load previous messages after login, and that use case require REST right?

Comment: That question depends on your service back-end.  That's your choice however if you go about REST, that's probably a good article : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/898992/RESTful-SignalR-Service